# USB debugging doesn´t work with physical device/flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, usb-debugging

Hey guys I created an App and my problem is than i can´t debug via usb cable since the latest Android Studio version Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2

If I run flutter doctor it shows me this error:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\josig\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    X Android SDK file not found: adb.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup
      for detailed instructions.
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem? I would be very thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if your platform-tools are not installed or not working.

Re-installing the platform tools might fix it:

- Open **Android Studio**
- Click **SDK Manager** in the toolbar or click Tools > **SDK Manager**
- Click SDK Tools, then uncheck Android-SDK Platform-Tools.
- After this, open C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and delete the platform-tools folder.
- Go back to Android Studio and in the SDK Tools, check-mark ‘✓’ Android-SDK Platform-Tools (reinstall).

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-unable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio/#:%7E:text=This%20generally%20occurs%20if%20the,Tools%20(as%20shown%20above).)

Comment: Thank you Sir this could be the solution but if I uncheck it and want to uninstall it, it just freezes midway. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: Look into the Source link that I posted, there is another way of doing it: re-installing platform-tools from command line. Try that.